# Cannot connect to bazel server

Tags: bazel

I'm new to Bazel, and installed Bazel on CentOS 7. I installed it by using "yum install bazel" with version of "0.14.0- (@non-git)"

When starting bazel, it always hung with following message:

"Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it..."

The batch mode however works, but client/server mode always hung. Wondering how to debug this issue?

Comment: What version is this? How did you install it?

Comment: Hi Jin, 

Thanks for the response.

I installed it using "yum install bazel" and the version is below:

$ JAVA_HOME=/usr /usr/bin/bazel version
Build label: 0.14.0- (@non-git)
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Jun 1 14:20:59 2018 (1527862859)
Build timestamp: 1527862859
Build timestamp as int: 1527862859

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information, so it's obvious to other SO users. Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using bazel binary from our github releases?  https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases

Answer (score 0):

I believe bazel uses your `loopback` interface so if that is not configured correctly that could be the cause of your issues. The reason batch mode works is because according to the docs

`If [batch mode is] set, Bazel will be run as just a client process without a server.`

Answer (score 0):

`bazel` server listens on `IPv6` address of `loopback` interface. If you have firewall rules to drop `IPv6` packets, you need to allow `bazel` traffic.

My issue was solved after adding these two rules:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -s ip6-localhost -d ip6-localhost -p tcp -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -s ip6-localhost -d ip6-localhost -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```